# Handling a multi line text incoming into a web service

Tags: java, string, web-services, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I am working on a webservice which receives an object "Person". A "Person" will have a field in it called "message" (String). The message can be any text that the client puts into it. It can extend to many lines and may have special characters in it too.

Now, in the Service Layer, Is it a good option to declare the 'message' field as String. or are there any better options.

If I use String type for "message", will the exact text that the user sends be recieved in the service layer or do I have to add any encoders/decoders?

I use this "message" that the client sends to send emails using sendmail.

---Advance Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Not encoders, but yes you will have to change the text slightly: The new line character in the incoming text will be different depending on the operating system/browser, and according to Email standard [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) Section 2.1:

> Messages are divided into lines of characters.  A line is a series
>   of    characters that is delimited with the two characters
>   carriage-return    and line-feed; that is, the carriage return (CR)
>   character (ASCII    value 13) followed immediately by the line feed
>   (LF) character (ASCII    value 10).  (The carriage-return/line-feed
>   pair is usually written in    this document as "CRLF".)

In Java, `CRLF` is represented as `"\r\n"`, so you will need to replace the line breaks in the text with that, this is best achieved using a RegEx, as follows:

```
message = message.replaceAll("\\r?\\n", "\r\n")
```